# Advice on how to handle one user bugging another in chat as a RO

Tags: discussion, chat

As a Room Owner I'm on a look out for possible troublesome interactions between users to nip it in the bud before it escalates.  What I am looking for is advice in how to find out if one user is really bugging another user.

My first though was to invite the user I suspect is being begged into a new room and ask them if they need me to step in.  This way they can feel safe to share if they want the other user to stop.  If they do say it is a problem then I would invite the offending user into their own room and explain what is going on and ask them to stop.  If they do not after that then I can kick them.  Not sure if this the best to handle it.

My other thought was just to leave a message in the main room like *Need me to step in here?* and then handle it from there publicly in the room.  I'm not so sure about this approach as I do not want to shame a user in front of everyone and I fell it puts the user that is being bugged on the spot to call out the offending user in the room.

If you guys could please share your thoughts and advice on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ideal scenario is that if a user is being "bugged" they custom flag for a moderator - this keeps things as anonymous as possible and in most cases I've seen - the behaviour ends up requiring more than just a kick (and isn't room specific).

I'd advise against taking someone into a new room as all chat messages are public - if someone is annoying someone even though you're trying to help you're only drawing attention to yourself and potentially making yourself another target to be bugged, and if someone isn't being annoying and happen to read the transcript they'll probably not end up too happy of your perceived opinion of them.

For users that aren't familiar with the chat system, that you feel either don't know how or know there is a system to deal with such behaviour, you can always read who you think is bugging someone's "most recent messages" - then either kick the user from your room if appropriate, or raise a custom mod flag on behalf of the user so we're aware there's an issue.

Comment: For a user who knows chat then I just let them deal with it and issue kicks for any behavior in the room that we do not want?

Comment: @NathanOliver basically... there's nothing stopping you from trying to intervene or help out, but if there's an "iffy" situation going on in chat - they tend to escalate fairly quickly and it's best to avoid being pulled in - despite your good intentions :(

Comment: OK.  Thanks for the information.  I'll let the mods have all the fun ;)